# C# implement generic method of interface

Tags: c#

Please help me to make this code work.

Now it fails on row `x => x.Model` with error message:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type

I don't have ideas.
Thank you.

```
interface IFetchStrategy<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> Apply<TProperty>();
}
class ModelFetchStrategy : IFetchStrategy<UserCar>
{
    public Expression<Func<UserCar, Model>> Apply<Model>()
    {
        return x => x.Model;
    }
}
class Model { }
class UserCar
{
     public Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

I need to use this strategies with similar code:

```
IEnumerable<UserCar> Get(IEnumerable<IFetchStrategy<UserCar>> strategies)
```

Comment: I can see why it is failing, but I don't have any idea what the intended operation is. Where are you using `TProperty` here? I can't see how it relates to `Model` in the way you are using it.

Comment: I edited code for better understanding.

Comment: `IFetchStrategy<TEntity>.Apply<TProperty>` has to work for any property type supplied by the user. If you want to use a specific property (`Model` in this case) you need to move the `TProperty` type parameter into the `IFetchStrategy` interface i.e. `IFetchStrategy<TEntity, TProperty>`.

Comment: With your realization it would be impossible to use this strategies together. I added new code in initial post.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that "Model" is not what you think it is. It is not an instance of the "Model" class, but rather it is a template property with a name (basically it is "TProperty" by a different name). Instead "Apply" has to take in no templates parameter.

```
interface IFetchStrategy<TEntity, TProperty> where TEntity : class
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> Apply();
}
class ModelFetchStrategy : IFetchStrategy<UserCar, Model>
{
    public Expression<Func<UserCar, Model>> Apply()
    {
        return x => x.Model;
    }
}
class Model { }
class UserCar
{
    public Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This implementation restricts me from using my method Get(IEnumerable<IFetchStrategy<UserCar>> strategies)...

Comment: Best advice is to do Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> and cast your results. Any better advice than that would need more info on the usage of IFetchStrategy.